# Binary to Hex to a File in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, vector

I have a binary vector which I converted to hex. I want this hex data to go to a .bin(or any other fornat) file. Since this is a vector,I tried to first convert it to a string so that the hex data can be formatted and then output to a file. Please see below the code I was trying to use. Also shown is the snapshot of the problem. As you can see, all the converted hex data is present in 1 cell. I want it to be byte wise for each cell.[image]

```
my_new_vector = binaryVectorToHex(M);  %M is my input binary matrix 
%cellfun(FormatHexStr, mat2cell(my_new_vector), 'UniformOutput', false)
%new_vector = mat2cell(my_new_vector);  
vect2str(my_new_vector);  %[matlab file exchange function][2] for converting vector to string
FormatHexStr(my_new_vector,2);    %FormatHexStr is a function for formatting hex values which requires a hex string as an input [function is here][3]
[n_rows,n_cols] = size(my_new_vector);
fileID = fopen('my_flipped_data.bin','wt');
for row = 1:n_cols
fprintf(fileID,'%d\n',my_new_vector(:,row));
end
fclose(fileID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the binary values into blocks of 8 in a uint8 (byte) variable, then write it to file.

```
nbytes = floor(length(M)/8);
bytevec = zeros(1,nbytes, 'uint8');
for i = 1:8
  bytevec = bytevec + uint8((2^(8-i))*M(i:8:end));
end
fileID = fopen('my_flipped_data.bin','wb');
fwrite(fileID, bytevec);
fclose(fileID);
```

This writes the first bit as the MSB of the first byte.  Use (2^(i-1)) for first bit as LSB.

Comment: keep getting this error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals." The matrix M contains only 1s and 0s.